# Gradle hangs forever but sudo gradle works

Tags: gradle

So I'm using gradle 2.4 on Mac OSX, and it was working fine. But then I restarted my system and now running anything with gradle even just `gradle` causes it to hang forever with no output and no error. But if I do `sudo gradle` it works fine. It's a hassle to type `sudo` all the time, is there any known workaround?

Comment: Basically no idea why you need to run gradle with sudo. It's *definitely* not good idea - as with everything when it comes to running processes with excessive privileges. Instead of running gradle with sudo fix privileges.

Comment: I'd check if there are some files/directories accessible to root only. Start with your $HOME/.gradle where Gradle stores locks, caches, and various other files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran `gradle -d` to get better logging and see what was going on and it was stalling out on the message 
`20:36:10.713 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /127.0.0.3.` when I wasn't running with `sudo` so naturally I did `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 255.0.0.0` and now it just says 
`20:35:56.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /127.0.0.3.
20:35:56.668 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Cannot connect to address /127.0.0.3, skipping.
2` and proceeds with the build and works fine. That was a weird one...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue on RHEL 7.6, anyone can help out with a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Well, `sudo gradle` command will launch gradle with sudo rights and any 'sub-command'. 
As of now, the only workaround I can think off is the `alias`. You feel free to come up with better solutions if any.

Here is how:

Open `~/.bash_profile`

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add below line

```
echo 'your_root_password' | sudo -S gradle
```

Close `~/.bash_profile` and execute

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Don't do this. This is a stupid way how to workaround the problem likely to cause new ones.